# clearing a float left not working

Tags: html, css

can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here. I've tried to write the clear:both; also inside the floated elements but nothing seems to work.

I would like those small orange boxes inside the green border and not like this (see image).

[image]

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Pv6m2/) and code:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .wrap {
        border:solid 2px green;
    }
    .wrap div {
        margin: 0 0 0 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 67px;
        float:left;
    }
    .wrap div span {
        display:block;
        background-color:orange;
        margin:2px;
    }
    .clear {
        clear:both;
    }
</style>


<div class="wrap">
    <div>
        <span>xx</span>
        <span>xx</span>
        <span>xx</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>yy</span>
        <span>yy</span>
        <span>yy</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>zz</span>
        <span>zz</span>
        <span>zz</span>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Pv6m2/2/)

You're floating the `<div class="clear">`. That's why it does not work.

Try this selector for the floating `divs` instead so it does **not** match the clearing `div`:

```
.wrap div:not(.clear) {
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 67px;
    float:left;
}
```

Another way of solving this, is to add `float: none` to your clearing class:

```
.clear {
    clear: both;
    float: none !important;
}
```

Comment: thanks @kilian for pointing why it does not work! I've tried and tried but haven't seen that I float the clearing <div> I've added a class to the <div>s inside the wrap except the clearing one...

Answer (score 4):

add

```
display: inline-block;
```

to your `wrap` container css

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/Pv6m2/1/

Comment: why has the wrap to be display:inline-block; ? it is what I want(!) but I don't understand why it is like this, can u please explain

Answer (score 1):

Add `float:left;` on the .`wrap` div
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Pv6m2/4/)

Answer (score 1):

It is happening because `.wrap` does not have any height.

Add

```
overflow:hidden;
```

to `.wrap`. It will give height to it.

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/hiral/Pv6m2/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
.wrap {
        border:solid 2px green;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
```

This should be in your css.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively use

```
.wrap {
    border: solid 2px green;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

and remove the `<div class="clear"></div>`

All of the other answers are perfectly fine too. Enjoy learning about floats!